# Animate a MKmapview to a certain geopoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

How can I animate an MKMapView to certain lat and lng?

I have a map that is displayed when the user opens the app. When a user clicks a certain button I want the map to move to a specificc lat/lng.

Is there not an animateTo(CLLocation) method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will animate to roughly the center of continental US:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = mapView.region;
region.center.latitude = 39.833333;
region.center.longitude = -98.58333;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 60;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 60;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

set your "center" to your latitude/longitude coordinates, choose an appropriate span, and let setRegion to its thing.

Comment: Does this not work [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([selectedLat doubleValue], [selectedLng doubleValue])];

Comment: yes, setCenterCoordinate works equally well, setRegion allows for the span of the region to be defined at the same time so the centering can be combined with a zoom-like operation

Answer (score 1):

This will scroll the map view to your new location:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D yourCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng);    
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:yourCoordinate animated:YES];
```